# Symfony $this->getUser() without doctrine associations (OneToMany)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, one-to-many, symfony6

In Symfony, we can get current logged-in user data using $this->getUser(), but my problem is when I access this statement, I am getting all the user-associated data set. which has OneToMany relationships with another entity, and it has a lot of data.

Example:

User Entity

`

```
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=10)
     *
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $email;


    /**
     * @var array
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    protected $roles;


    /**
     * One User has Many Posts.
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Post", mappedBy="user", fetch="LAZY")
     *
     *
     */
    private Collection  $posts;
```

`

Post Entity

`

```
class Post
{
    /**
    * @var string
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=11)
    */
    private $id;

  

    /**
    * Many posts have one user.
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="post", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="userId", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    private $user;
```

`

I am looking to get rid of the user-associated data set or limit the associated data set to limit 1.

Thank you for the help in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found solution after hours of search.

You will be required to add Symfony Serializer #Ignore attribute on the Entity class.

Example

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Ignore;

class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     */
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 10)]
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string')]
    protected $email;


    /**
     * @var array
     */
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'json')]
    protected $roles;


    /**
     * @var Post
     */
    #[ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity: 'App\Entity\Post', mappedBy: 'user', fetch: 'LAZY')]
    #[Ignore]
    private Collection  $posts;
```

I hope this help someone. Cheers!